# Timer event handler doesn't write on console

Tags: c#, timer

I know this might be strange but I have a timer and I have an event handler for Elapsed event that writes on Console, but when I start the application, the timer start properly, the event fire properly, too. However, the result doesn't show in console except after I press a button, which made me put two `Console.ReadKey()` so the application won't terminate.

Here is the code in `Program.cs`:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer(100);
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(WriteOnConsole);
        timer.Start();
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void WriteOnConsole(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A B C D");
    }
```

Please inform me if I haven't mentioned enough information.

Comment: What is the type of your timer? Which timer class (System.Timers, System.Threading....etc.)?

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ken2k, I think its `System.Timers.Timer` from the event and constructor

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange behaviour of Console.ReadKey() with multithreading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143931/strange-behaviour-of-console-readkey-with-multithreading)

Answer (score 8):

The `ReadKey()` blocks the `WriteLine()`. After you pressed one key, the first `ReadKey` is finished and the pending writes to the console are flushed.

As this obviously only is a small sample to demonstrate the problem it is hard to suggest a better alternative.

One could be to use some sort of wait handle to exit the application only when a certain condition is met.

Comment: But only the first one. And only if you haven't already written to it. I think there's something weird in the way the console is initialized, basically.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Which "first one" do you mean? The first `ReadKey` or the first `WriteLine`?

Comment: Coincidentally, I think this has the same cause as the thing I asked about yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143931/strange-behaviour-of-console-readkey-with-multithreading

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: The first `ReadKey`. Note how the second `ReadKey` call *doesn't* block anything.

Comment: @JonSkeet The first `ReadKey`doesn't block anything either on my machine.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, thank you Eivind. I'm still a beginner in C#, I used `Console.ReadLine()` which I never thought I'd use it for that purpose

Comment: @ken2k: Indeed, on mine neither. It outputs right away. Strange.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: What do you mean the second call to ReadKey _doesn't_ block anything ? Do you mean to say that it isn't a blocking call (which returns only after the console received a key press) ? Because it is...

Comment: @EduardDumitru: It's a blocking call, but it doesn't prevent another thread from writing output.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Oh. sorry.. I misunderstood. Of course it doesn't. You know what I thought you meant... Dangerously homonymic terms ended up in the same little package :) `Console.ReadKey`

Comment: @EduardDumitru: The point is that the "of course" isn't really an "of course" because when it's broken, the first `ReadKey` *does* block the `WriteLine` in the other thread.

Answer (score 3):

Try writing an empty string from the 1st thread, before anything else, 
thus initializing the Console:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write(string.Empty);
    Timer timer = new Timer(100);
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(WriteOnConsole);
    timer.Start();
    Console.ReadKey();
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void WriteOnConsole(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("A B C D");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this in another question - you don't even need a timer, just *any* two threads where one thread is reading from the console and another is writing.

It looks like the initialization for `Console` is somewhat broken - the *first* call to it will effectively take out a lock until it completes, preventing any other console access.

If you write:

```
Console.WriteLine("Starting");
```

at the start of your code, all will be fine, for example. It's not like `ReadKey` (or any other read operation) blocks all console output *in general* - it's just in the first call.

Comment: I can't reproduce: the OP's code works fine on my machine (edit: I mean it outputs directly to the console without the need to press a key)

Comment: This is a race condition, and it seems to only occur on some systems.