# ElapsedEventHandler not raised

Tags: c#, events

I am trying to follow an example from a c# tutorial to trigger an event from the timer class when a certain amount of time has passed, however it doesn't seem to work.
Here is the code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Timers.Timer tmr = new System.Timers.Timer();
        tmr.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimerTickHandler);
        tmr.Interval = 1000;
        tmr.Enabled = true;
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void TimerTickHandler(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write("\rprinting: {0}", e.SignalTime.ToString());
    }

}
```

I attached the TimerTickHandler on to the elapsed event and after each second it should print the time to the screen, but I am not getting any output.
Any clue as to where I am going wrong?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yet another case of the .NET 4.5 change, ReadKey() takes a lock that prevents other threads from writing to the console.  Your handler *does* execute, it just can't blabber to the console while it is in input mode.  Set a breakpoint with the debugger to see this.

Comment: I think I should report this as a bug, if it hasn't already been reported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix this by changing `Console.ReadKey()` to `Console.ReadLine()`.

Here's [a thread discussing why `Console.ReadKey()` has strange effects on multithreading in Console apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143931/strange-behaviour-of-console-readkey-with-multithreading).

Essentially, `Console.ReadKey()` has taken a lock on an internal object which `Console.Write()` also tries to take a lock on. So when the timer goes off, the `Console.Write()` that you're using to report it blocks, because `Console.ReadKey()` has taken a lock on the same object that `Console.Write()` wants to use.

I consider this a bug in `Console.ReadKey()`. Holding a lock while waiting on I/O is always a bug, IMHO.

Also note that if you change the `Console.Write()` to `Debug.WriteLine()` and attach a debugger, it will also work even if you leave `Console.ReadKey()` in.

Comment: Brilliant, that's sorted it. An explanation would be nice :-).