# Sometimes thread does not start

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I faced with some problem I cannot understand why it is happening.
Here is simple example:

```
class ConsoleApp
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Thread workThread = new Thread(ThreadProc);
    //Console.WriteLine("Starting"); // uncomment this
    workThread.Start();
    Console.ReadKey(true); // first ReadKey
    Console.ReadKey(true); // second ReadKey
  }

  static void ThreadProc()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("ThreadProc started");
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      int timeout = rnd.Next(500, 1000);
      Thread.Sleep(timeout);
      Console.WriteLine("ThreadProc {0} slept {1} ms", i, timeout);
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this, workThread doesn't start until I press some key (after first ReadKey). If I uncomment first Console.WriteLine, workThread starts immediately.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: A race condition. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143931/strange-behaviour-of-console-readkey-with-multithreading

Comment: I copied your code and tried this, but the thread immediately starts, regardless of commenting or uncommenting that line.

Comment: I can't repeat this. What environment is this running under?

Comment: Alexander, Try with replacing `Console.ReadKey` with `System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new Form());`

Comment: Thanks, the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143931/strange-behaviour-of-console-readkey-with-multithreading explained everything. I tried to use Debug.WriteLine() and saw that thread is actually started, but Console.WriteLine locked execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an ideal case of **race condition**. Here you are creating a thread and subsequently starting it. But keep in mind, there is a delay for the thread to actually run once you call `start` method on it. Possibly, this delay give chance for your `Console.ReadKey` method to get into flow of execution and wait for user input. At this stage, `Console.ReadKey` method block your console through taking a lock on `Console.InternalSyncObject`, and blocks waiting for input. This case other execution path to block until we key in.  Once you press the Key, which indirectly release the lock on `Console.InternalSyncObject` and allow the thread continue its execution. I presume, this is what happening in your case.

Though it is not to replace what you are trying to achieve, you can see the thread executing when you replace `Console.RedKey` to `Console.ReadLine()`.

Comment: The thread starts immediately. It is `Console.WriteLine` that waits for the console lock to be released before it finishes executing..

Answer (score 0):

Static class `Console` is thread-safe, there's a lock inside. Sometimes `ReadKey` call takes the lock before calls inside your `ThreadProc`. It is called "race condition"