# Why ThreadPool thread doesn't print anything to console unless main thread print first

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am very confused about below code snippet.

```
 //Console.WriteLine("Main thread: Doing other work here...");
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
            state =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(200);
                    Console.WriteLine("In computeBoundOp: state={0} " + i, state);
                }
            }, 5);
 //Console.WriteLine("Hit <Enter> to end this program...");
 Console.ReadKey();
```

Acutally the thread pool thread doesn't print anything unless I uncomment either of the "Console.WriteLine()" before or after the ThreadPool part.(Note I even have a readkey there at the end of main thread)

Or else, to make the background thread print something, I have to use a manualresethandle to let main thread wait the thread to complete.

Any idea how this happenes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

ReadKey() locks the Console.InternalSyncObject and blocks waiting for input while the writes wait. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143931/strange-behaviour-of-console-readkey-with-multithreading) for some additional info.

This produces a race condition between when Console.WriteLine() writes and before Console.ReadKey() reads, which explains why those in the comments see it as working fine on their machines (and I did not).

Put another Console.ReadKey() after the initial. Press a button and continue. You'll then get what you were initially expecting.

Use something like:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo cki = null;
do
{
    if (Console.IsKeyAvailable)
        cki = Console.ReadKey(); 
} while(true);
```

... to not block.

Comment: Thanks.By replacing "Readkey" with this block(need some minor modification though), it works.