# C# SSH.Net asynchronous command read and write

Tags: c#, asynchronous, ssh, async-await

I am trying to write an SSH script for some routers/switches to read out information using SSH.Net. I want to build it asynchronous because they are pretty slow with high latency.

I can connect and send a command, but if I try to read it out, I just get some blank lines. If I run the `WriteLine()` method like 7 times in a row, I see like 2 of the expected outputs. I hope you can help me.

Here is my code:

```js
private static string _srv = "255.255.255.255";
private static string _usr = "looping";
private static string _pwd = "louie";

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    GetDslamData();
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static async void GetDslamData()
{
    using (SshClient _ssh = new SshClient(_srv, _usr, _pwd))
    {
        try
        {
            _ssh.Connect();

            if (_ssh.IsConnected)
            {
                ShellStream stream = _ssh.CreateShellStream("mainstream", 0, 0, 0, 0, 2048);

                if (stream.CanWrite)
                {
                    stream.WriteLine("help");
                }

                if (stream.CanRead)
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                    int i = 0;

                    if ((i = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(_ssh.ConnectionInfo.Encoding.GetString(buffer, 0, i));
                    }
                }
            }

            _ssh.Disconnect();
            _ssh.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Verbindungsfehler! Es konnte keine SSH-Session gestartet werden.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you're disposing `_ssh` twice; once explicitly, then again implicitly when you leave the `using()` scope - you should drop the first one.

Second, because you're not awaiting `GetDslamData()` you're dropping straight through to `Console.ReadKey()` while `GetDslamData()` keeps running.  While much of `Console` is thread safe, there are at least some reports of performing `WriteLine()` while in a `ReadKey()` causing deadlocks or other unwelcome behaviour; e.g.:

[Strange behaviour of Console.ReadKey() with multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143931/strange-behaviour-of-console-readkey-with-multithreading)

http://putridparrot.com/blog/console-readkey-and-console-writeline-deadlock/

[Calling Console.WriteLine from multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079980/calling-console-writeline-from-multiple-threads)

So instead, change your `GetDslamData()` signature to this:

```
private static async Task GetDslamData()
```

and `Main()` to this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    GetDslamData().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

or if you are using C# 7.1+, to this:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await GetDslamData();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

That way `ReadKey()` won't be executed until `GetDslamData()` is complete.  If you only had the `ReadKey()` there because you noticed your app was otherwise exiting immediately, just drop it after changing the code as above.