# How to execute async/await command that can show result

Tags: c#, multithreading, ssh, task

I tried the below code to execute command in Task.Run.

```
SshClient ssh;
    public Form1()
    {
    InitializeComponent();

//BackGround Login is needed.
ConnectionInfo info = new ConnectionInfo(hostNameOrIpAddr, portNo, userName,
    new AuthenticationMethod[] {
    new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(userName, passWord)
ssh = new SshClient(info);
ssh.Connect();
cmd = ssh.CreateCommand(commandString);
    }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Task.Run(()=>{
SshCommand cmd = ssh.CreateCommand(commandString);
cmd.Execute();
Console.WriteLine(cmd.Result.ToString());
;});
}
```

But it doesn't work well.
The reason is probably to Dispose the stream immediatly after starting the task.

Comment: Hey @yur and welcome to StackOverflow. Please format your code to improve readability which will in turn improve the chance that someone will answer your question :) 

Also please be more specific about "...it doesn't work well." What are you expecting to happen and what is happening?

Comment: You want to Asynchronous Receive to capture data.  See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48808074/c-sharp-ssh-net-asynchronous-command-read-and-write

Comment: your code does not compile

Comment: my bet is maybe your server is requiring a captcha of sorts about press a key or something and its stopping automated connections from finishing normally.  So you might have to first interact with it as a shell stream and then send your commands.

Answer (score 0):

**One of the ways to use async/await is as following:**

> Note: The async keyword turns a method into an async method, which allows you to use the await keyword in its body.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var result = await Task.Run(() => RunSshCmd());
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

**Let's say running ssh command will take 5 seconds to finish, just example.**

```
private string RunSshCmd() {       
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    return "Done.";
}
```

> Note: await can only be used inside an async method.

Comment: With your answer, what I  want to do is achieved!

Comment: Glad to hear that :)